# Esri ArcSDE 10.3.1 Query Inspire Metadata from Oracle (11g) Enterprise GeoDB via SQL

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, sql, arcgis-10.3, oracle-dbms, oracle-spatial

As the title says - I want to create a query in Oracle SQL which will read all dates from the geoprocessing history which can be found using ArcCatalog to show the "Description"-tab from a feature. (You need to change the settings of ArcCatalog to use the following "Metadata Style")

If possible I just want to use SQL only - no python or arcpy.

[image: Settings changed in ArcCatalog to INSPIRE Metadata Directive]

[image]

The first approach I used was to query the "cdate" field within "sde.layers" table with the following query:

```
SELECT Upper(sde.layers.owner 
         || '.' 
         || sde.layers.table_name)                                    AS 
   feature_name, 
   ( To_date('1970-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') + sde.layers.cdate / 86400 ) AS 
   last_update 
FROM   sde.layers 
WHERE  sde.layers.owner LIKE 'SDE_V_%' 
ORDER  BY last_update DESC;
```

The query above will list the creation date of every layer within the ArcSDE which is not what I need.

I tried querying the SDE_XML_DOC2 table which should contain the information I described above but wasn't successful because oracle developer always outputs the following error:

Query:

```
SELECT Xmltype(xml_doc, 871) 
FROM   sde.sde_xml_doc2 
WHERE  sde_xml_id = 8641;
```

Error:

```
LPX-00217 invalid character error
```

I tried different character sets (1 US7ASCII, 170 WIN1250, 171 WIN1251, 178 WIN1252, 871 UTF-8) within the XMLType function but all of them returned the same error.

I'am stuck at this point and need some help. **The general idea is to get the last modified date of all layers within the sde (vector and raster).**

Answer (score 1):

SQL-only / database-only possible solutions:

A. - add a timestamp column to every layer using systimestamp as default value, then query for latest timestamp

B. - add a trigger ON INSERT and ON UPDATE to every layer table, that updates last modified date value for each layer, on a table of your own.

Comment: While that is possible i would like to use the data already given by esri/arcgis. Thank you for the different approach. It would be nice to get an example querying the already given tables.